# VBA: how to null a Variant?

Tags: vba, variant

I have the following Variant:

```
Dim comboitems() As Variant
```

that I use in all the code as an array that contains the values of a `ComboBox` control.

In a certain point of the code, I need to clear/empty/null `comboitems()`. How can I do? I tried all of the following options without any success.

```
comboitems = ""
comboitems = Null
comboitems = Nothing
Set comboitems = ""
Set comboitems = Null
Set comboitems = Nothing
comboitems() = ""
comboitems() = Null
comboitems() = Nothing
Set comboitems() = ""
Set comboitems() = Null
Set comboitems() = Nothing
```

The error that I get is this:

[image]

Comment: `Erase comboitems` perhaps?

Comment: `ReDim` without `preserve`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For variant arrays, you'd clear them with the erase command.

```
Erase comboitems
```

Here's a handy reference guide for dealing with arrays in vba:

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/